# Bitbucket pipeline runner issue

Tags: kubernetes, sonarqube, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbukcet pipeline runner in my kubernetes cluster

```
kubectl get po -A --watch
NAMESPACE              NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
default                runner-01-26kgg                                 2/2     Running   0               44h
```

These containers have the hostname as

```
/ # hostname 
runner-01-26kgg
```

But when I check the hostname from pipeline its showing the hostname as

```
+ echo "Executing on runner: ${BITBUCKET_PIPE_RUN_ON}"
echo "Runner container hostname: $(hostname)"
Executing on runner: 
Runner container hostname: 9ce8de576a8c
```

and im not sure which container its showing.

My pipeline is below

```
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
  branches:
    '{master}':
      - step:
          name: Build and Analyze
          runs-on:
            - self.hosted
            - linux
          script:
            - |
              echo "Executing on runner: ${BITBUCKET_PIPE_RUN_ON}"
              echo "Runner container hostname: $(hostname)"
              echo "Environment variables:"
              printenv
```

Runners are configured with labels self.hosted,linux and are active in bitbucket. Can I get a help to run the job in same runner.

image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
branches:
'{master}':
- step:
name: Build and Analyze
runs-on:
- self.hosted
- linux
script:
- |
echo "Executing on runner: ${BITBUCKET_PIPE_RUN_ON}"
echo "Runner container hostname: $(hostname)"
echo "Environment variables:"
printenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipelines run in docker containers spawned in the runner, not directly in the runner. That's why `$(hostname)` evals to a container ID.

Also you made up the `$BITBUCKET_PIPE_RUN_ON` variable so it is empty. See https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/ for the existing variables that can be used in scripts.

```
          runs-on:
            - self.hosted
            - linux
```

this should be enough so that the step runs on your self-hosted runner. Maybe I don't understand your question, sorry.